# Reportes en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, reportviewer, parametros, imprimir

Hola Tengo un problema con report viewer en visual studio funciona con datatable pero a la hora de pasar parametros tira esto y no lo puedo solucionar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ReportProcessingException: La definición de informe no es válida o no la admite esta versión de Reporting Services. Puede ser el resultado de la publicación de una definición de informe de una versión posterior de Reporting Services o que la definición de informe contenga código XML con formato incorrecto o que no sea válida según el esquema de la definición de informe. Detalles: La definición de informe tiene un espacio de nombres de destino no válido 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' que no se puede actualizar.

Comment: Código y errores van como **texto**. Te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te informes de la manera adecuada de formular una pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Hola. La respuesta no la tenes no????

Comment: El error es claro "versiones". Con qué versión creaste el reporte?

Comment: lo cree con visual studio 2017 y lo ejecute en el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver el problema. Primero instale la ultima vercion de microsoft.reportviewer.common y microsoft.reportviewer.winforms.
Despues copias y pegas el informe para que se genere de nuevo y eliminas el viejo. Eso a mi me funciono.